# Bash window title not restored after exit

Tags: macos, bash, ssh

I have a problem with the window title in the Terminal window on OS X:

1. Start Terminal. Window title is "bash"
2. Type "ssh external" to connect to an external server. Window title is "user@external:~"
3. Type "exit". I am now back at my local machine, but the window title still says "user@external:~".

How do I make the window title return to "bash", which I assume would be correct since I have logged out of the external server and returned to my local machine?

My ~/.bash_profile has the same PS1 value:

export PS1='\w$ '

Answer (score 0):

You define the title by echoing a specially formulated string to your terminal.

You could define:

```
function update_title {
   echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007" ;
}
```

and then use:

```
update_title
```

each time you want to update it.

If you want it updated "all the time", you could use your shell's support for "just-before-displaying the prompt" functions.
ex, in (a decently recent) bash:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
```

But I find this a bit overkill : it re sets the title before *every* prompt, not just when needed...

Comment: So you could say the reason this happens is that the prompt is set at login, but not at logout?

Comment: not exactly, but in your case it seems so.

Comment: You may have it set in your login scripts? (difficult to say what exactly happen, could be set in a variety of places)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that sets the title any string you give it, or hostname and current directory if you don't provide a title.  I call it "xst" for "xterm set title".

```
xst () 
{ 
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -e "\x1b]0;${HOSTNAME}:${PWD}\x07";
    else
        echo -e "\x1b]0;$*\x07";
    fi
}
```